# How can i overcome this error while creating a local host server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, localhost, mean-stack

[here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVmp9.png)I have typed in this code and in the browser showing error

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req , res) =>{
    res.end('Hello fromm the server!');
});

server.listen(8000, '127.0.0.1', () => {
    console.log('Listening to request on port 8000');
})
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to recreate this issue. Have you executed your node script in your terminal?

In this example, I've name the file 'index.js'

```
node index.js
```

Your terminal should show 'Listening to request on port 8000' after you execute your node script.

[image]